# Функция не видит состояние компонента

Tags: reactjs

Доброго времени суток.

Есть компонент родителя:

```js
<Parent>
  <Child 
    actions={[
      {
        title: 'Click on me'
      }
    ]}
  />
</Parent>
```

и компонент дочернего элемента (`<Child />`), который добавляет к `action` некий `handle`, который будет вызываться при клике на него

```js
function Child(props) {
  const { actions } = props;
  
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
  const [selfActions, setSelfActions] = React.useState(actions);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('updated state', state);
  }, [state]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    _treatmentActions(selfActions);
  }, [])
  
  function check() {
    console.log('state in check function is ', state);
    // always is 0
  }
  
  _treatmentActions(actions) {
    const updatedActions = actions.map(function(action) {
      action.handle = {
        ...action?.handle,
        onClick: check
      };

      return action;
    });
    
    setSelfActions([...updatedActions]);
  }
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => setState(state + 1)}>state + 1</button>
      
      <Actions data={selfActions} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

компонент `<Actions />`

```js
function Actions(props) {
  const { data } = props;
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {(data && data.map(function(action, actionIndex) {
        <React.Fragment key={actionIndex}>
          <button onClick={action.handle && action.handle.onClick}>click on me, please</button>
        </React.Fragment>
      }))}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Вопрос ->
Почему, после того как несколько раз изменишь состояние в `<Child />` через кнопку `button` при клике на кнопку `button` из компонента `<Actions />` состояние в `<Child />` равно 0? хотя оно будет равно N, где N - количество раз, кликнутого на кнопку `button` в компоненте `<Child />`